# python-pptx color legend not showing same colors as graph

Tags: python-3.x, powerpoint, python-pptx

This drives me nuts.

```
    chart_AllData = slideref.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.BAR_STACKED_100, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data)

    chart = chart_AllData.chart        
    plot = chart.plots[0]
    pointCount = 0
    for answer in consolidatedAnswersList: # Looping over the answer codes
        print('answer: ', answer)
        catBar = plot.series[pointCount].points
        for cat in catBar: # Looping over the categories (= the declarations)
            fill = cat.format.fill
            fill.solid()
            colorString = ccpStatistics.gAnswerCodeColorDict.get(answer, 'FFFFFF')
            r = int(colorString[0]+colorString[1], 16)
            g = int(colorString[2]+colorString[3], 16)
            b = int(colorString[4]+colorString[5], 16)
            fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(r , g , b)
            print('setting ', answer, ' to ', colorString)
        pointCount += 1

    print(ccpStatistics.gAnswerCodeColorDict)

    category_axis = chart.category_axis
    category_axis.minor_tick_mark = XL_TICK_MARK.OUTSIDE
    category_axis.tick_labels.font.italic = True
    category_axis.tick_labels.font.size = Pt(12)

    value_axis = chart.value_axis       
    value_axis.format.line.color.rgb = RGBColor(0 , 0 , 0)
    value_axis.tick_labels.font.size = Pt(int(thisPageDict.get('SCALEFONTSIZE', ['18'])[0]))
    value_axis.major_tick_mark = XL_TICK_MARK.OUTSIDE
    value_axis.has_major_gridlines = True
    value_axis.tick_labels.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0,0,0)
    value_axis.major_tick_mark.number_format = '0.0"%"'

    chart.has_legend = True
    chart.legend.position = XL_LEGEND_POSITION.RIGHT
    chart.legend.include_in_layout = False # set to true
    chart.legend.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0,0,0)
    chart.legend.font.size = Pt(int(thisPageDict.get('LEGENDSIZE', ['12'])[0]))

    plot.has_data_labels = True
    data_labels = plot.data_labels

    data_labels.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.CENTER
    data_labels.font.size = Pt(int(thisPageDict.get('LEGENDSIZE', ['10'])[0]))
    data_labels.font.color.rgb = RGBColor(0x00, 0x00, 0x00)
```

The content of the ccpStatistics.gAnswerCodeColorDict is as follows:

```
{'oaq_NoAnswer': 'DCDCDC', 'maq_NoAnswer': 'DCDCDC', 'Answer code': 'Answer code color', '1': 'FF0000', '2': 'FF6600', '3': 'FFC301', '4': '00B050', 'OK': '00B050', 'NOK': 'FF0000', 'NA': '333333', 'NEU': 'FF00FF', 'maq': '3A87AD', 'dq': '660000', 'txta': '660000', 'nq': '660000'}
```

Now, the graph gets properly colored according to the settings in series... And the names of the series in the legend is OK too... But the colors of the legend does not correspond to the colors in the bar.

NOTE, similar code seems to work well in other methods. I'm at wit's end now.

[See the resulting ppt chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9c5pM.png)

Comment: To clarify: "Not Answered" should be gray. The legend works in other methods.

Comment: Series that is green in the chart gets red in the legend.

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the color at the series level rather than at the individual point level.

```
fill = series.format.fill
fill.solid()
fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(r, g, b)
```

Comment: Sorry for late feedback, and it will be even later since I cannot try it out right now. But I will be back and check this solution - your gracious support is NOT forgotten. Thanks.

Comment: Worked splendidly.Thanks, Scanny.